# The best Web3 providers online

Tags: web3js, infura

Does anyone know what are the most popular web3 providers online? (Or is Infura the only one?)

Comment: Infura is for sure the most popular

Comment: @jasper I agree with you, but are there any alternatives?

Comment: quiknode.io is a drop-in replacement with a free tier (disclosure, work for quiknode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a quick google away:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/7kcc5z/alternatives_to_remote_node_services_like_infura/

The comments on this thread basically say that besides Infura the best provider and the alternative is run your own (light)node.

Comment: Please add some details about what is behind the link. If the link goes dead, this answer should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: As I did now or do you need more data?

Comment: This answer is completely outdated now. Look at Ibrendanl's answer for up-to-date information.

Answer (score 15):

Over the past year, many teams have been busy building infrastructure services to better support the ecosystem. There are now a number of options available to developers - which is fantastic for the overall Ethereum ecosystem.

There are generally two types of solutions - the companies that abstract away node management and just provide APIs (let's call them API Providers) & the companies that will spin up dedicated or shared nodes for you (let's call them Node providers).  There are pros and cons to both approaches.

In the API Provider category, you have:

- Infura (https://infura.io) - The original, it's been around awhile and thus has earned developer trust.
- (Edit: Shut down in Jan'20) - Nodesmith (https://nodesmith.io) - Full disclosure upfront, I am one of the founders here. Our APIs are fully compliant with the standard Ethereum JSON RPC interface - but we've built out sophisticated middleware layer that makes our response times faster and more reliable than alternatives.
- Alchemy (https://alchemyapi.io/) - A relatively newer player, they currently have an invite only product that looks promising. I've heard from various blockchain teams that they are pleased with the service.

On the Node provider side, you have many options:

- BlockDaemon (https://blockdaemon.com) - very impressive team and they do a lot more than just Ethereum nodes.
- QuickNode (https://quiknode.io/)
- BlockCypher (https://blockcypher.com)

Apologies to the providers I've missed - there are definitely more.

There are also some innovative projects coming online that are seeking to build a decentralized & trustless network of node providers.  One great example of this is the Pocket Network (https://www.pokt.network/).

Comment: This subdivision is interesting, but I didn't understand the differences. In the ethereum documentation I read that infura is classified as Ethereum API as a service, while BlockCypher as Ethereum Web APIs. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The most popular is [Infura](https://infura.io) as you said but there is a few others hosted ones:

- [QuikNode](https://quiknode.io)
- [BlockCypher](https://www.blockcypher.com)

Other solutions imply bootstrapping and syncing your own node which could take some time, or use a Parity node.

Comment: Hi, I read your comment and wanted to ask if you can help me with this doubt. In the ethereum documentation I read that infura is classified as Ethereum API as a service, while BlockCypher as Ethereum Web APIs. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Another I'll add is [Alchemy API](http://alchemyapi.io). You need to request an invite for now but Alchemy is really promising.